# Effective Field Theory with Higgs integrated out

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, standard-model, higgs, effective-field-theory

I have been trying to get the low energy EFT Lagrangian from EW Lagrangian of standard model not with the effective action principle but with Equation of Motion

EW Lagrangian part concerning Higgs

$$\mathcal{L}_{EW}^{\varphi} = (D_{\mu}\varphi)^{\dagger}(D^{\mu}\varphi)-\mu^2 \varphi^{\dagger}\varphi-\lambda(\varphi^{\dagger}\varphi)^2+\bar{\psi}y\varphi \psi$$

with $(D_{\mu}\varphi)^{\dagger}(D^{\mu}\varphi) = (\partial_{\mu}\varphi)^{\dagger}(\partial^{\mu}\varphi)+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{v+h}{v}\Big)^2 \Big[\frac{g^2 v^2}{4}W^{+}_{\mu}W_{-}^{\mu}+ \frac{(g^2+g'^2) v^2}{4}Z_{\mu}Z^{\mu}\Big]= (\partial_{\mu}\varphi)^{\dagger}(\partial^{\mu}\varphi)+\frac{1}{v^2}\varphi^{\dagger}\varphi \Big[\frac{g^2 v^2}{4}W^{+}_{\mu}W_{-}^{\mu}+ \frac{(g^2+g'^2) v^2}{4}Z_{\mu}Z^{\mu}\Big]$

Equation of motion for heavy Higgs ignoring kinetic terms

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \varphi}-\partial_{\mu}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\varphi)} = 0$$

where second term is neglected since kinetic terms are neglected hence $\varphi$ becomes

$$\varphi = \frac{\frac{1}{v^2}\varphi^{\dagger}\Big[\frac{g^2 v^2}{4}W^{+}_{\mu}W_{-}^{\mu}+ \frac{(g^2+g'^2) v^2}{4}Z_{\mu}Z^{\mu}\Big]+\bar{\psi}y\psi-\mu^2\varphi^{\dagger}}{2\lambda(\varphi^{\dagger})^2}$$

Then this should be substituted back into $\mathcal{L}_{EW}^{\varphi}$, thus we have our EFT Lagrangian with Higgs boson integrated out. However I am not sure how to confirm that this is the correct EFT Lagrangian.

Comment: My impression was that using equations of motion to eliminate a field is equivalent to integrating out that field to tree level - and ignores higher-loop effects; though I need to figure out exactly what that means (don't know if this helps)

Comment: 1. Your last equation does not make sense mathematically. ($\varphi$ is an ${\rm SU}(2)$ doublet.) 2. Given the fact that the observed value of the Higgs mass being relatively close to $M_W$ and $M_Z$ (and $m_t$ being even larger than $M_h$), integrating out the SM-Higgs  while keeping at the same time $W$, $Z$ and $t$ as dynamical fields does not make sense physically. (EFT at which energy scale?)

Comment: EFT at low energy scales, i should have been more specific so there might still be terms including W and Z bosons after integrating out the Higgs. For W and Z bosons, the effective Lagrangian looks way simpler however when Higgs and top quark integrated out low energy effective Lagrangians by using this equation of motion method looks too complicated.